# Font-locking based on top-level s-expression keyword

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-lock

I'm writing an emacs major mode for a programming environment which supports two slightly different programming languages.  Both are lisps (one is Scheme), so both use s-expressions. The two languages are differentiated by their function definition keyword: scheme uses `define`, while the other language (which is called xtlang) uses `bind-func`

So, in the same buffer, I have

```
(define foo        ; this is scheme
   (lambda (a)
      (+ scheme-fn a))

(bind-func bar     ; this is xtlang
   (lambda (b)
      (* xtlang-fn b))
```

I've got the font-locking working, using something like

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
                        '(("(\\(define\\)\\>"
                           (1 font-lock-keyword-face))
                          ("(\\(bind-func\\)\\>"
                           (1 font-lock-keyword-face))
                          ("\\<scheme-fn\\>"
                           (0 font-lock-function-name-face))
                          ("\\<xtlang-fn\\>"
                           (0 font-lock-function-name-face))
                          ))
```

**What I'd like to be able to do is to be able to colour the parens differently based on the language (scheme/xtlang).**

So, colour all the parens in the form red if the top-level defun is a `define`, and blue if it's a `bind-func`, while still highlighting all the keywords/functions within the forms as normal.

This may require multi-line font locking, since the `define`/`bind-func` will probably be on a previous line to the keywords to be highlighted.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452615/emacs-is-there-a-clear-example-of-multi-line-font-locking) suggests that `font-lock-multiline` in conjunction with match-anchored in `font-lock-keywords` may be the answer, but then goes on to suggest that `font-lock-multiline` should only be used in situations where the multi-line aspect is the exception rather than the rule.

My other option seems to be to use `syntax-propertize`, but I'm a bit confused about how that works - the documentation is a bit sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is utilizing the following fact:

> MATCHER can be either the regexp to search for, or the function name
>   to call to make the search (called with one argument, the limit of the
>   search;

In other words, you could replace regexps like `"\\<scheme-fn\\>"` with a function that repeatedly search for the regexp using `re-search-forward`, and return if a match is found *in the correct context*.

For a concrete example of a package that use this technique, look at `cwarn-mode`, which is part of the standard Emacs distribution.