# emacs custom php tags highlight syntax

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

I want to set custom color background in  tags, but other do not touch

```lisp
(define-derived-mode php-mode fundamental-mode
  "php-mode"
  :syntax-table php-syntax-table
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(php-keywords)))

(defvar php-syntax-table (make-syntax-table) "Syntax table for php-mode")
(make-face 'php-region-face)
(set-face-background 'php-region-face "red")
(setq php-keywords '(("<\\?php[[:ascii:]]*?\\?>" 0 'php-region-face t)))
```

But highlight background tags is not correctly, see below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to setup multiline font-lock and define the boundaries of the font-lock search (so it doesn't take too much time). My information (and this code) comes from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452615/emacs-is-there-a-clear-example-of-multi-line-font-locking).

Here, I define multiline font-locking to take place within tags (< ... >). If this is added to your define-derived mode, it works as you describe.

```lisp
(set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-multiline) t)
(add-hook 'font-lock-extend-region-functions
          'test-font-lock-extend-region)

(defun test-font-lock-extend-region ()
  "Extend the search region to include an entire SGML tag."
  ;; Avoid compiler warnings about these global variables from font-lock.el.
  ;; See the documentation for variable `font-lock-extend-region-functions'.
  (eval-when-compile (defvar font-lock-beg) (defvar font-lock-end))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char font-lock-beg)
    (let ((found (or (re-search-backward "<" nil t) (point-min))))
(goto-char font-lock-end)
(when (re-search-forward ">" nil t)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (setq font-lock-end (point)))
(setq font-lock-beg found))))
```

EDIT: for some reason, SO doesn't like my code formatting.